# Merge into table from two matlab tables with different date/time format

Tags: matlab, join, merge

I have two Matlab tables and want to merge into, but the time intervals are different. thanks in advance

1. Table TEST_1 with the time intervals of 3 hours and the key data DINDEX.

> ```
> DUT                DINDEX    
> 2018/8/4           0.7   
> 2018/8/4 3:00:00   1.3   
> 2018/8/4 9:00:00   0.7   
> 2017/8/4 9:00:00   0.7   
> 2018/10/5          0     
> 2018/10/5 9:00:00  0.3   
> 2018/10/5 18:00:00 1     
> 2018/10/5 21:00:00 0.7   
> 2018/10/10         0.7
> ```

for example,

the first row show time range is between  2018/8/4 00:00:00 and 2018/8/4 3:00:00 with 3 hours time interval.

the second row show time range is between  2018/8/4 3:00:00 and 2018/8/4 6:00:00 with 3 hours time interval, and so forth.

2. DATE of Table TABLE_2 has no regular.

> ```
> UT                                  KP  
> 2018/8/4 1:02:05.421000       
> 2018/8/4 4:02:06.921000                 
> 2018/8/4 9:02:08.421000       
> 2017/8/4 9:02:09.921000                 
> 2018/10/5 1:02:11.421000      
> 2018/10/5 10:02:14.421000               
> 2018/10/5 19:02:15.921000     
> 2018/10/5 21:02:17.421000               
> 2018/10/10 0:02:18.921000
> ```

3. And now, I want to merge into the field KP of Table TEST_2 using the key data DINDEX in Table TEST_1 by time, what I expect is:

> ```
> UT                                  KP 
> 2018/8/4 1:02:05.421000             0.7
> 2018/8/4 4:02:06.921000             1.3
> 2018/8/4 9:02:08.421000             0.7
> 2017/8/4 9:02:09.921000             0.7
> 2018/10/5 1:02:11.421000            0  
> 2018/10/5 10:02:14.421000           0.3
> 2018/10/5 19:02:15.921000           1  
> 2018/10/5 21:02:17.421000           0.7
> 2018/10/10 0:02:18.921000           0.7
> ```

the first UT (2018/8/4 1:02:05.421000)  is between 2018/8/4 00:00:00 and 2018/8/4 3:00:00, so the KP of the first UT is 0.7, corresponds to the first DINDEX.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are the data sorted as perfectly as you show in your example? If so, can you just copy the column over? If not, you can match up the entries between `TEST_1` and `TEST_2`: iterate over each date in the timetables and equate the first two entries. Then, check the time difference between the subsequent entries (in `TEST_2`) is what you expect (the same as `TEST_1`). If so, you can then allocate the data as you show. If the time differences do not match up as expected, I guess you will have to do some kind of manual correction.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I can copy the column, but the two Matlab tables are with different date/time formats

Comment: Another option would be to match up the columns by iterating over each element in `TEST_2`. Get the date of that element. Then, find the earliest element in `TEST_2` with that date, and find the time associated with that element. Then, subtract this time from the current element you are at. Or is the data not as simple to work with as you show in your example?

Comment: The real data is a bit more complicated, but my example above is also intercepted from the real data, trying to find an implementable and efficient method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the `timetable` operation [`retime`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timetable.retime.html). This allows you to "interpolate" time series data in a variety of ways. Here's a fabricated example that I think is somewhat similar to what you're describing:

First make some regularly-spaced data, put into a timetable

```
>> regularData = timetable(datetime(2018,8,4) + hours(0:6:48)', randi(10, 9, 1))
regularData =
  9x1 timetable
            Time            Var1
    ____________________    ____
    04-Aug-2018 00:00:00      9
    04-Aug-2018 06:00:00      6
    04-Aug-2018 12:00:00      6
    04-Aug-2018 18:00:00     10
    05-Aug-2018 00:00:00      3
    05-Aug-2018 06:00:00      8
    05-Aug-2018 12:00:00      8
    05-Aug-2018 18:00:00      4
    06-Aug-2018 00:00:00      6
```

These are the times that we wish to interpolate to

```
>> wantTimes = datetime(2018,8,4) + hours(sort(48 * rand(5,1)))
wantTimes =
  5x1 datetime array
   04-Aug-2018 02:35:22
   04-Aug-2018 03:38:27
   05-Aug-2018 01:28:41
   05-Aug-2018 13:24:00
   05-Aug-2018 20:49:57
```

Perform the interpolation using 'nearest' values.

```
>> retime(regularData, wantTimes, 'nearest')
ans =
  5x1 timetable
            Time            Var1
    ____________________    ____
    04-Aug-2018 02:35:22     9
    04-Aug-2018 03:38:27     6
    05-Aug-2018 01:28:41     3
    05-Aug-2018 13:24:00     8
```